# Openmp: increase for loop iteration number

Tags: c, for-loop, numbers, iteration, openmp

I have this `parallel for` loop

```
struct p
{
    int n;
    double *l;
}

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i) shared(p)
for (i = 0; i < p.n; ++i)
{
    DoSomething(p, i);
}
```

Now, it is possible that inside `DoSomething()`, `p.n` is increased because new elements are added to `p.l`. I'd like to process these elements in a parallel fashion. OpenMP manual states that `parallel for` can't be used with lists, so `DoSomething()` adds these `p.l`'s new elements to another list which is processed sequentially and then it is joined back with `p.l`. I don't like this workaround. Anyone knows a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: How do you expect OpenMP to spawn jobs without knowing how many there will be? How should a job work on an element without the element already existing? That's just impossible.

Comment: When all jobs have finished, check again the conditions and if new elements have spawned, start more jobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A construct to support dynamic execution was added to OpenMP 3.0 and it is the `task` construct. Tasks are added to a queue and then executed as concurrently as possible. A sample code would look like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{
    #pragma omp single
    for (i = 0; i < p.n; ++i)
    {
       #pragma omp task
       DoSomething(p, i);
    }
}
```

This will spawn a new parallel region. One of the threads will execute the `for` loop and create a new OpenMP task for each value of `i`. Each different `DoSomething()` call will be converted to a task and will later execute inside an idle thread. There is a problem though: if one of the tasks add new values to `p.l`, it might happen after the creator thread has already exited the `for` loop. This could be fixed using task synchronisation constructs and an outer loop like this:

```
#pragma omp single
{
   i = 0;
   while (i < p.n)
   {
      for (; i < p.n; ++i)
      {
         #pragma omp task
         DoSomething(p, i);
      }
      #pragma omp taskwait
      #pragma omp flush
   }
}
```

The `taskwait` construct makes for the thread to wait until all queued tasks are executed. If new elements were added to the list, the condition of the `while` would become true again and a new round of tasks creation will happen. The `flush` construct is supposed to synchronise the memory view between threads and e.g. update optimised register variables with the value from the shared storage.

OpenMP 3.0 is supported by all modern C compilers except MSVC, which is stuck at OpenMP 2.0.

Comment: It's worth a shot. I'll give it a try since your answer is the closest to what I need

Comment: Don't I need a #pragma omp parallel somewhere?

Comment: The second code example only presents the inner `single` construct. You still need the outer `parallel` region.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since tasks are what I need, but I need also to tweak my code accordingly. I cannot spawn 300k threads if p.n is 300 000 (and sometimes could also be 3 000 000)

Comment: OpenMP tasks are _not_ threads. They are pieces of code (think callbacks) queued in a task pool and then executed by the thread team of the parallel region. But you would need to tweak your code for another reason - if each computation is relatively cheap then the task overhead could be significant. In that case it would be wiser to give each task a range of points and tweak the range size in order to get the best performance.

Comment: Yes, DoSomething is cheap, but p.n could be very big, even 45 millions